# actionscript 3 - deleting children from stage issue

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So im creating a game where the ai shoot at the player. This issue im having is when the AI fires a bullet and is killed before the bullet is destroyed, the bullet freezes in mid air due to the AI being removed from the stage. Here is a video showing what I mean : http://i.gyazo.com/a13a43467ae8c6c3d8b1c988b7010bc2.mp4

The ai's bullets are stored in an array and im wondering if there is a way to remove the children added to the stage by the ai when the ai itself is removed from the stage.

This is the code which handles an AI being hit by a PLAYER bullet. The ai's bullets are stored in an identical way but in another class/file.

```
        for (var i = _bullets.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            for (var j = enemies.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                if (_bullets[i].hitTestObject(enemies[j])) {
                    stage.removeChild(enemies[j]); //removes the ai 
                    stage.removeChild(_bullets[i]); //removes the players bullet
                    _bullets.splice(i, 1); 
                    enemies.splice(j, 1);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: The code you posted shows the removal of an enemy and a bullet. But the real question is why the bullets freeze when the enemy is removed. The enemy and the bullets it creates should be independent objects. Please post the code that moves the bullets (and when not being executed freezes them) and where it is located in your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do what you describe, but I don't recommend it. To do it you can listen for `Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE` and perform some kind of cleanup:

```
// in your AI class
addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, removedFromStage);
function removedFromStage(e:Event):void {
    // remove all the bullets
    for each(var bullet:Bullet in _bullets){
        stage.removeChild(bullet);
    }
    _bullets.length = 0;
}
```

However, this approach isn't realistic (the bullets will disappear mid-flight instead of continuing on their path as you'd expect) and it isn't a very good design.

The better way would be to store all your bullets in your main game class. The AI is responsible for "firing" a bullet, but after that the main class handles the bullet travel, collisions, etc. If you separate your logic like this, you won't have more problems like the the one you ran into.

There are many ways you could implement such a design, but here's a simple example I've used many times:

**Your Main game class:**

```
public class Main {

    // a list of all enemies in the game
    private var enemies:Vector.<Enemy> = new <Enemy>[];

    // a list of all bullets in the game
    private var bullets:Vector.<Bullet> = new <Bullet>[];

    // adds a new enemy to the game
    public function addEnemy():void {
        var enemy:Enemy = new Enemy(this); // pass a reference to this Main class
        enemies.push(enemy);
        addChild(enemy);
    }

    // removes an enemy from the game
    public function removeEnemy(enemy:Enemy):void {
        enemies.splice(enemies.indexOf(enemy), 1);
        removeChild(enemy);
    }

    // adds a new bullet to the game
    public function addBullet():void {
        var bullet:Bullet = new Bullet(this); // pass a reference to this Main class
        bullets.push(bullet);
        addChild(bullet);
    }

    // removes a bullet from the game
    public function removeBullet(bullet:Bullet):void {
        bullets.splice(bullets.indexOf(bullet), 1);
        removeChild(bullet);
    }
}
```

**Your Enemy class:**

```
public class Enemy {

    // a reference to the Main class
    public var main:Main;

    public function Enemy(main:Main){
        // store the reference to the Main class
        this.main = main;
    }

    // to shoot a bullet, call the Main class
    public function shoot():void {
        main.addBullet();
    }

    // to kill the enemy, call the Main class
    public function die():void {
        main.removeEnemy(this);
    }
}
```

**Your Bullet class:**

```
public class Bullet {

    // a reference to the Main class
    public var main:Main;

    public function Bullet(main:Main){
        // store the reference to the Main class
        this.main = main;
    }

    // to remove the bullet when it hits something, call the Main class
    public function collide():void {
        main.removeBullet(this);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the Main class is responsible for adding and removing enemies and bullets, and various other places in code simply call back to the Main class. This separation will prevent issues like you ran into and be much more flexible down the road.

Comment: Passing Main to every class is bad design. Instead, communicate the removal of bullets and enemies as well as the creation of Bullets by dispatching Events from Bullet and Enemy class.

Comment: I disagree. Passing Main as a reference is better for the following reasons: 1) It declares the dependency on Main in the constructor, 2) Events are slow (really slow), which matters for games, 3) Event bubbling up the display list is making the entire game even more dependent on the display list. A better design would be to completely separate your display objects from your game data.

Comment: Also, the passing of Main was not really my point or an answer to the question, but rather it was the move of adding and removing of game objects to the Main class. Referencing Main could be done several other ways, passing a reference seemed the least departure from what he currently has.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply, I tested the removedfromstage event and it seems to only remove 1 bullet from the ai, if the ai has more than 1 bullet in the air it removes 1 and the other freezes. Not really had time to look into it yet, but gonna try doing the bullets in the main class as you suggested when I have more time later on. Thanks again.

Comment: @Aaron 1) being dependent on Main is the issue, not how it gets the reference 2) premature optimisation is the source of all evil 3) I did not say anything about bubbling. Your answer is right, it's just not good design and that's what I wanted to point out.

Comment: @lukedb In order to remove all the AI's bullets, you'll need to loop over the bullets array and remove each one. I've updated my example to show how this could be done.

Comment: @null Sure, replace "Main" with "World" or a controller or an interface... but a dependency on some high level container class is not an out-right "bad" design in a highly interactive state machine like a game. If it was a UI I'd agree. As for using events, you didn't mention bubbling, but that means you want to add listeners to every single game object. There are many potential problems there, too. It's certainly a way to do it, but by no means "good" vs "bad". Cheers.